# ¿Que camino tomar, ante las malas redacciones en las preguntas?

Tags: discusión, ediciones, idioma-español

Hace un tiempo que intento ser un usuario activo y colaborativo en la comunidad, resolviendo problemas, corrigiendo y/o editando errores o malas expresiones; Pero hoy me plantee porqué existen tantas preguntas escritas en pésima forma, las reglas puntuación del español son iguales para todos, donde van mayúsculas y minúsculas, como separar ideas en oraciones y/o párrafos, etc. es algo mas allá de los dialectos que se manejan dentro de la comunidad.

Lo que lleva a plantearme, que hago cuando me encuentro con preguntas que incumplen muchas de esas normas y que dificultan su lectura, ya que en muchas casos hay que reescribir prácticamente toda la pregunta.

¿Que opción les parece mas correcta de tomar a ustedes?

Por mi parte, no me parece correcto cerrar la pregunta por una mala redacción, porque muchas veces llegan a ser interesantes si fuese bien redactadas y con buena expresión. Por otro lado, si edito la pregunta completa y se la dejo a lo que a mi parecer es un formato mas correcto y atendible (según las reglas del español), quienes pregunten se pueden acostumbrar a que alguien le corregirá su pregunta y no se tomaran el trabajo de preguntar de manera correcta.

---

> Esta discusión se enfoca mas en problemas sobre la mala escritura
>   (Ortografía, sintaxis y semántica), no sobre el contenido pobre de la
>   pregunta (No posee código, no muestra el error, etc) a los que muchas
>   veces se hace referencia.

Comment: No se cierran preguntas por su mala redacción aunque hay casos en el que la formulacion de la pregunta puede llevar a un tipo de cierre u otro y salvarse del cierre con una reformulacion. En cuanto a editar el formato, ten en cuenta que a veces para usuarios nuevos no es del todo claro y que editandoselo pueden aprender cómo hacer una correcta indentacion, citas, saltos de linea, uso de negrita ... etc.

Comment: Yo personalmente, trato de cambiarlo todo, especialmente si la pregunta puede ser interesante. Ortografía, redacción, separación de párrafos,formato de código...todo ello ayuda a que la pregunta tenga mas posibilidades de recibir una respuesta. Te animo a que edites todo lo que consideres necesario.

Comment: Es que hay algunas preguntas que tienen delito: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/149128/revisions. Una cosa es no saber usar las opciones de formateo o tener algún error gramatical u ortográfico y luego están las preguntas que parece que se han escrito de resaca o directamente desde el bar

Answer (score 3):

Mi criterio sería el siguiente:

- Si ayuda a que sea respondida **mejórala**
- Si no puedes entenderla por su mala redacción deberías **votar para cerrarla** ya que un motivo de cierre es "Esta pregunta es completamente confusa"

Ahora en cuanto a la parte difícil... si tiene una falta de ortografía o un regionalismo y modificarlo implica muy popcos caracteres yo opinaría **que lo dejes así** a menos que haya otras cosas que mejorar, esto debido a que los usuarios también en su busacdor utilizan las mismas faltas de ortografía y podrías impedir que solucionen su problema por hacer un cambio irrelevante en mi opinión.

Comment: Para aclarar, un localismo no se debería modificar **jamás**. SOes acepta el español en todas sus formas. La interfaz del sitio está en español neutro, pero en las preguntas y respuestas podés usar la forma que vos quieras, y si la cambiás tenés altas chances de que se revierta la edición.

Comment: Por ello mismo comenté que no vale la pena cambiarlo en mi opinión :)

Answer (score -1):

Soy nuevo por acá, no tengo voto ni nada, sólo una opinión.

Sin animos de ofender, con todo respeto y admiración, su publicación también tiene un par de errores ortográficos, además, se entiende muy bien, así que, para ese tipo de situaciones, quizá está bien dejar pasar las preguntas.

Es totalmente cierto, que existen muchas búsquedas que llevan a esta plataforma, algunas de ellas, como es obvio, utilizando variedad lingüística (jerga), por lo que les será fácil encontrar la información a los que comparten la misma.

Si considera que la pregunta no se entiende, creo que debería esperar a ver si alguien más si lo hace, para comprender mejor el asunto y así reformular la pregunta. A veces los que buscan ayuda por medio de las preguntas, desconocen los nombres de algunas tecnologías e inventan sus cosas para darse a entender, por eso hay que tener un poco de paciencia.